# Arch Linux lvm on luks with btrfs

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, btrfs

[image]it's been 4days i'm trying to install arch linux with lvm on luks partitions with this architecture :

```
sda
|-> sda1 |- 256Mo EFI (/boot - fat)
|-> sda2 |- (LUKS encrypted)
         |-> cryptlvm(LVM)|
         |-> root |- ~6Go (/ - btrfs)
         |-> swap |- 2Go
```

i have done the installation without problems but when i reboot i got this screen after 10 sec of black screen

[after choosing arch linux on grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrEYc.png)
Can someone help me ?

The documentation that Ii'm using to install:

- https://infradoc.antoinethys.com/systeme/archlinux/install-luks-btrfs-efi.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS

(I didn't do the part of btrfs subvolume)

Comment: You seem to refer to something (a screenshot and some documentation?) that is not included or linked properly

Comment: Did you unlock the LUKS containers before arriving at this screen? If no, that's your problem; it's trying to bring up LVM to decrypt a LUKS container on top of LVM. I'm sure there's a way to tell Arch about that fact.